# Python project that uses external libraries on Android

Tags: android, python, external, libraries

I have a framework in python consisting of many scripts utilizing many external libraries (NumPy, Scikit, Librosa, Weka, Yaafe etc). Is there any way to get the whole thing to work on Android?

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​probably​

Answer (score 1):

You will have to port your project to [QPython for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hipipal.qpyplus&hl=en_GB). Several libraries  have been ported, you can find the Numpy port [here](https://github.com/qpython-android/QPypi-numpy), although not all your libraries have been ported, so you will have to port these yourself.